# Animated HTML splash screen changes size on a mobile device

Tags: html, css, flutter, flutter-web

I've made a Flutter web app for which I've implemented a splash screen using HTML and CSS. Everything works fine on a desktop device, however, when I access the website using my phone's Chrome and Brave browser, the splash screen itself gets bigger in size after around a second from being displayed, leading to this element being larger than it's supposed to be.

HTML code is a simple div element, while CSS attributes are as follows:

```
.center {
align-items: center;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your head tag.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```